# DbUpdateException occuring when adding a record to a database C#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

This is the first time I have used EntityModels and I am having trouble adding a new record to the database. An 'DbUpdateException' occurs in the SaveChanges() method, also I can not find the "Inner Exception".

[image: DbUpdateException]

```
    //this is the code in the Bookings class
    public void Save()
    {
        InsightEntities ie = new InsightEntities();

        ie.Bookings.Add(this);

        try
        {
            ie.SaveChanges(); //Error Occuring Here
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In case you need it here is the record I am trying to add:
(BookingId & DateEntered have default values in the database)

[image: Class: Booking]

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you catch the exception while debugging, what does its `.InnerException` property say?  (Hint: The message is *telling you* where to look for more information.)

Comment: Ahhhh sorry i was looking directly at the innerMessage without realising it was broken down, turns out it was having trouble converting datetime to smalldatetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't inserting the new record as it couldn't convert DateTime to smalldatetime,

Fixed this by changing the database column types to DateTime

All works now! :)